# Choosing A Random IP From Any Specific CIDR Range In C

Tags: c, networking, cidr

I am trying to create a function that'll be able to parse any IP/CIDR range and choose a random IP within this specific range as a string in C (including a `/32`, which would just return the single IP address each time). As of right now, I'm fine with it including reserved IPs (e.g. broadcast) and if I have trouble excluding those in the future, I'll post a separate question.

I am still fairly new to this area since I don't have much experience with using bitwise operators on integer's bits yet (I understand the bitwise operators themselves, but I'm trying to figure out how to use them with networking and IPs). I've also read most of [this](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers/53994#53994) question which gives a lot of great advice/guidance (thank you Ron Maupin for providing me with this), but I'm still struggling to get this function completely working.

I have nearly working code, but for some reason using a `/8` CIDR or anything smaller than `/24` results in odd behavior. Using `/16` and `/24` works as expected (those are all I've tested so far).

Here's the code I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        // IP/CIDR.
        char *sip = "10.0.0.0";
        uint8_t cidr = 8;

        // Randomize the rand() seed.
        time_t t;
        srand((unsigned) time(&t) + i);

        // Create in_addr and convert the IP string to a 32-bit integer.
        struct in_addr inaddr;
        inet_aton(sip, &inaddr);
        uint32_t ipaddr = inaddr.s_addr;

        // Get the mask (the complement of 2 to the power of the CIDR minus one).
        uint32_t mask = ((1 << cidr) - 1);

        // Generate a random number using rand().
        uint32_t randnum = rand(); // Also tried rand() % 256.

        // Attempt to pick a random IP from the CIDR range. We shift left by the CIDR range since it's big endian. 
        uint32_t newIP = ipaddr & mask | ((0x0000ffff & randnum) << cidr);

        // Convert the new IP to a string and print it.
        struct in_addr ip;
        ip.s_addr = newIP;

        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", inet_ntoa(ip));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This simply chooses a random IP 25 times from the given IP/CIDR. When using a `/8` (e.g. `10.0.0.0/8`), this is the output I receive:

```
10.220.186.0
10.180.229.0
10.231.159.0
10.24.70.0
10.217.108.0
10.50.250.0
10.170.108.0
10.48.139.0
10.183.205.0
10.61.48.0
10.3.221.0
10.161.252.0
10.48.1.0
10.146.183.0
10.138.139.0
10.33.27.0
10.19.70.0
10.109.253.0
10.5.8.0
10.124.154.0
10.109.145.0
10.53.29.0
10.223.111.0
10.18.229.0
10.255.99.0
```

The last octet is always `0`. I'd imagine I'm doing something incorrect when shifting to the left by the CIDR range when creating the random IP 32-bit integer. However, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do here.

When using a `/30` range (e.g. `192.168.90.4/30`), here's the output I receive:

```
192.168.90.68
192.168.90.196
192.168.90.68
192.168.90.68
192.168.90.68
192.168.90.4
192.168.90.196
192.168.90.68
192.168.90.196
192.168.90.68
192.168.90.132
192.168.90.4
192.168.90.196
192.168.90.68
192.168.90.196
192.168.90.196
192.168.90.4
192.168.90.68
192.168.90.132
192.168.90.4
192.168.90.68
192.168.90.68
192.168.90.132
192.168.90.196
192.168.90.196
```

It chooses `192.168.90.4` at times which is correct, but the other three random IPs are outside of the `/30` range, but within `192.168.90.0/24`.

When using a `/16` (e.g. `172.16.0.0/16` in this case), here's the output which is to be expected:

```
172.16.35.154
172.16.97.234
172.16.31.37
172.16.201.87
172.16.57.212
172.16.254.128
172.16.183.172
172.16.54.210
172.16.248.145
172.16.186.83
172.16.250.34
172.16.250.160
172.16.23.185
172.16.125.238
172.16.206.16
172.16.57.32
172.16.65.137
172.16.202.94
172.16.164.138
172.16.241.182
172.16.154.186
172.16.197.103
172.16.184.21
172.16.96.172
172.16.195.86
```

This works correctly with a `/24` as well (e.g. `192.168.90.0/24`):

```
192.168.90.253
192.168.90.156
192.168.90.65
192.168.90.189
192.168.90.22
192.168.90.238
192.168.90.150
192.168.90.106
192.168.90.63
192.168.90.64
192.168.90.64
192.168.90.54
192.168.90.104
192.168.90.110
192.168.90.34
192.168.90.187
192.168.90.202
192.168.90.73
192.168.90.206
192.168.90.13
192.168.90.15
192.168.90.220
192.168.90.114
192.168.90.125
192.168.90.70
```

I was wondering if anybody knew what I was doing wrong here. I apologize if I'm missing something obvious as well.

I am also developing this on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04 on the `5.4.0` kernel).

Any help would be highly appreciated and thank you for your time!

Comment: First question: What is your system's `RAND_MAX`? Second question: Why the static mask for the host part? It should be the inverse of the other mask, as in `0xFFFF0000` and `0x0000FFFF`. Net mask vs. host mask.

Comment: Decode IPv4 to `uint32_t` native, do your math, then shuffle it back into network-endian.

Comment: @tadman In `/usr/include/stdlib.h`, `RAND_MAX` is defined as 2147483647. I also tried undefining and redefining it in my program as `2147483647` just in case and had the same results as above.

Comment: At least it's not something stupid small like 32768. You should probably generate 4 bytes worth of `rand()`, then combine those into a random IPv4 address you can mask on to the other as necessary.

Comment: I think it would be simple to get a random 32-bit unsigned integer, then shift it right by the number of mask bits, then add it to the 32-bit unsigned network address. For example, `10.0.0.0/8`, you would shift the random number right by 8 bits (`/8`), then add it to the 32-bit unsigned integer of `10.0.0.0` (`10100000000000000000000000000000`).

Comment: @tadman, that really does not work if the mask ends within an octet, only if it falls on an octet boundary. Really, the random number simply needs to be as long as `32 - mask length`, then added to the network address.

Comment: @RonMaupin It works if you're using native endian for the calculations. Trying to do it network-endian is just a recipe for a mess.

Comment: @tadman, it does not matter because the conversion from text to integer can be done natively, the random and addition natively, then the native converted back to text. It is really very simple.

Comment: @RonMaupin It's from text to *network order*, not host order.

Comment: @tadman, if you do the math to convert the text to an unsigned integer, it is a native integer, not necessarily network byte order. Then, you do the native math to get the native result, and then do the math to convert it back to text. I do that all the time, and it works well.

Comment: @RonMaupin Why "do the math" when `inet_aton` does the proper conversion to host form, and you can flip that with `ntohl`?

Comment: @tadman, because I do not need to load a library that does the same math, plus a lot of other things that I really do not need to simply manipulate IP addresses. It looks simpler your way, but I do not need all the the other stuff in the library, and it really does the same math that I do, so it is simpler and faster to do it my way when I do not need everything else in the library.

Comment: @RonMaupin Your comments seem way off base here. This is not some exotic library, this is **part of the POSIX standard** and gets loaded wether you like it or not. It's part of `libc`. This is how things have been done *for decades*. If you parse IP addresses with your own code you're going to get things wrong. IPv4 can be expressed in many ways, not just `x.x.x.x`.

Comment: @tadman, it actually depends on the language you are using. I know how to parse all the valid forms of IPv4 and IPv6, and I use it all the time. Because I understand how to do it and how it works, I can do it across different programming languages.

Comment: @RonMaupin This is a C question, so stay focused on that, but even then, as C is a common foundation, you'll find these functions in many other languages.

Comment: @tadman, I did not post an answer, I provided comments that explained the principles behind how IPv4 addressing works so that the OP can actually understand it. In fact, under the covers, your answer ends up doing more calculations (text to network order to host order) that what I explained (text to host order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reworked this using host-endian calculations and also moved a lot of things out of the loop that shouldn't have been there in the first place:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  if (argc < 3) {
    printf("Usage: cidrrand net cidr_size\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  char *sip = argv[1];
  uint8_t cidr = atoi(argv[2]);

  srand(time(NULL));

  struct in_addr inaddr;
  inet_aton(sip, &inaddr);
  uint32_t ipaddr = ntohl(inaddr.s_addr);
  uint32_t host_mask = (1 << (32 - cidr)) - 1;

  for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
  {
    uint32_t host_rand = rand();

    // Attempt to pick a random IP from the CIDR range. We shift left by the CIDR range since it's big endian.
    uint32_t newIP = (ipaddr & ~host_mask) | (host_mask & host_rand);

    // Convert the new IP to a string and print it.
    struct in_addr ip;
    ip.s_addr = htonl(newIP);

    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", inet_ntoa(ip));
  }

  return 0;
}
```

When seeding random numbers, try and seed once and once only. Don't mess with it unless you have a specific goal relating to generating several reproducible series.

Answer (score 1):

Really useful topic here - thanks Christian, and kudos to Scott for revisited version of initial code.

Just in case if anyone will land here with a similar question for IPv6, I have created a short examples for both IPv4 and IPv6 generators [here](https://github.com/defanator/cidr-random/).

It includes binary representation of addresses and masks for better understanding.

The thing I'm currently struggling with in IPv6 is reusing all available octets from single 32-bit random value while iterating over IPv6 octets that need to be changed according to netmask:

https://github.com/defanator/cidr-random/blob/master/cidr_random6.c#L133-L150

Anyway, hope it will be useful as a starting point for anyone interested.